# MySQL + PHP: Pull down 1000 entries at a time, increment to next 1000, repeat

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Good morning!

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly simple, but I haven't been able to find a working answer. I'm trying to pull down entries 0-999 from a table, then 1000-1999, 2000-2999, etc. Here's what I've got so far, but it's still pulling down 0-999+ as it increments

```
for($k = 0; $k < 10000; $k += 1000)
{
    $query = "select * from TABLENAME LIMIT 1000 OFFSET " . $k;
        .....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for($k = 0; $k < 10000; $k += 1000)
{
    $query = "select * from TABLENAME LIMIT {$k},1000";
        .....
}
```

Comment: add the `order by ` at the end to be 100% sure of the result

Comment: @jcho360 why is there need for `ORDER BY` clause? the question doesn't specify any ordering

Comment: Nope running into the same issue. Added the order by as well, still hits all of my entries.

Comment: Results are printed as: select * from MyTablesName order by registration_id LIMIT 0,1000 {"multicast_id":googlegloudmessagingidhere,"success":8,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":2,"results":

Comment: what do you mean by "still hits all of my entries" ? that query returns you all the rows from ur table?

Comment: Yeah the query is returning all of the rows in my table. I only have 8 entries, but I'm trying to make sure it's decently scalable for when I have ~250,000

Comment: well... if you have only 8 entries of course `LIMIT 0,1000` will return you all the rows since 1000 > 8 .. :) try to use `LIMIT 0,2` to see that it works

Comment: I tested this query with a table with 5012 records and yes it pulls 1000 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = 0;
$end = 0;
for($k = 0; $k < 10000; $k += 1000)
{

   $flag = $start+999;
   $end = 1000;
    $query = "select * from TABLENAME LIMIT $start,$end";

    .....
   $start =  $flag+1;
}
```

Comment: you got i wrong `$end` should be fixed (1000 entries) "With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return." Please read some more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html